# Flutter json adapter pattern query

Tags: json, flutter, dart

[Control character in string (at line 377, character 54)
"value": "import java.lang.reflect.Field;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rAA7.png)

Someone please help me resolve this error. In my code I am using adapter pattern and using static json string to render data. The json string is valid, I checked with online formatter.

My code has model, json string, adapter and view.

What I tried - Improving the mapping in the adapter in vain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the image provided it is clear that the cause of the error is the missing `"` in the json, you just need to add the missing `"` and the error should disappear:

original answer:
"value": "import java.lang.reflect.Field;

Fixed answer:
"value": "import java.lang.reflect.Field";